# Excel-VBA : Run-time error '91'

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, vba

I'm new to VBA and I have the following code of a button :

```
Private cell2 As Range
Private ModMail As String
Private BacMail As String
Private QtyMail As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim LR2 As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        LR2 = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell2 In .Range("B13:B" & LR2)
            If cell2.Value = "" Then
                cell2.Value = TextBox1.Text
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell2

        If cell2.Offset(, 2).Text <> 0 Then
            If cell2.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 199, 206) Then
                Label8.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 2).Text
                Label9.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 3).Text
                Label10.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 4).Text
                Label12.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 5).Text
                Label13.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 6).Text
                Label28.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 7).Text
                Label30.Caption = cell2.Offset(, 8).Text
                CommandButton2.Enabled = True
            Else
                cell2.Value = ""
                MsgBox "Votre bac existe déjà", vbExclamation, "Bac double"
                Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
                Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
            End If
        Else
            cell2.Value = ""
            MsgBox "Prière de saisir un numéro de bac valide", vbExclamation, "Numéro de bac invalide"
            Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
            Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, when I fill a textbox and I click the button I get this Error message :

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

When I click the debug button in error message box it highlights the following line :

```
If cell2.offset(, 2).text <> 0 then
```

I tried to change `0` by `"0"` and `.text` by `.value` but in vain.

Thank you

Comment: Your `cell2` variable is the last cell from `Range("B13:B" & LR2)`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Hello  sir, thank you for the response, YES but that just a part of the code : after filling a textbox and clicking the button1. The value of the textbox is transferred to a cell and then via Vlookup functions I get many informations to display as labels on the userform.

Comment: Does cell contain error? What's its value?

Comment: After running the userform, no value is given to the cell. The error prevents that from happening

Comment: `cell2` will be `Nothing` once you exit the `For Each cell2 in .Range("B13:B" & LR2)` loop - it is only valid inside that loop unless it hits the `Exit For` (which it won't do unless you have empty cells between B13 and the last non-empty cell in column B).

Comment: Do you have any blank cells between B13 and the last non-empty cell in column B?

Comment: If there's no blank cell between `B13` and `LR2` then variable `cell2` will be unset and you will get this error.

Comment: @YowE3K No I don't have any blank cells between B13 and the last non-empty cell.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I'm pretty sure there are blank cells between B13 and LR2. My Excel file is designed to ensure that condition.

Comment: "No I don't have any blank cells between B13 and the last non-empty cell" - "I'm pretty sure there are blank cells between B13 and LR2. My Excel file is designed to ensure that condition" - Those two statements are contradictory.  If there are no blank cells in your range, then the code will fail.